How do I add information into a specific range?
I'm very new to all this, but I've created a sheet where we can get some information from our clients, but I’d like to make it more dynamic, so I'm trying to program it to at a click of a button I can get the information from one sheet to another. I was able to do that, but I wanted to know how I put this data in separate ranges from the same sheet.
Like, I want that the information I fill in on one sheet, when I click on the bottom goes to another sheet to an specific range depending on specific information, for example month
function cadastrar() {
  var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var nome = ss.getRange('E10').getValue();
  var proveniencia = ss.getRange('E12').getValue();
  var meio = ss.getRange ('E14').getValue();
  var faturado = ss.getRange('E16').getValue();


  if (nome == '' ||   proveniencia == '' || meio == '' || faturado == '' ){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Oie, esqueceu de por alguma coisa ai amore!");
  return
   }


 var info = [nome, proveniencia, meio, faturado]

 var ss =ss.getSheetByName('triagem 24');

 last_row = ss.getLastRow();

 for (let i=0; i<5; i++){
  ss.getRange(last_row+1,i+1).setvalue(info[i]);
 }

this is what I have, but I would like that the info from cadastrar whent to the "triagem 24" into a specific range of lines and columns

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Add data to next available row and column1 of Sheet0:
function cadastrar() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const [a, , b, , c, , d] = sh.getRange("E10:E16").getValues()
  if (a == '' || b == '' || c == '' || d == '') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Alert: at least one is null");
    return;
  }
  var info = [a, b, c, d].map(e => [e])
  var osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, info.length).setValues(info)
}

